# Regex issue using ICU regex to find numbers not inside parentheses

Tags: objective-c, regex, regexkitlite

I'm trying to scan a given string for a number. The number cannot be after "v/v./vol/vol.", and cannot be inside parentheses. Here's what I have:

```
NSString *regex = @"(?i)(?<!v|vol|vol\\.|v\\.)\\d{1,4}(?![\\(]{0}.*\\))";
NSLog(@"Result: %@", [@"test test test 4334 test test" stringByMatching:regex]);
NSLog(@"Result: %@", [@"test test test(4334) test test" stringByMatching:regex]);
NSLog(@"Result: %@", [@"test test test(vol.4334) test test" stringByMatching:regex]);
```

Infuriatingly, this does not work. My regex can be separated into four parts:

`(?i)` - make regex case insensitive

`(?<!v|vol|vol\\.|v\\.)` - negative look-behind assertion for v/v./vol/vol.

`\\d{1,4}` - the number I'm looking for, 1-4 digits.

`(?![\\(]{0}.*\\))` - negative look-ahead assertion: number cannot be preceding a ), unless there's a ( before it.

Maddeningly, if I take out the look-behind assertion, it works. What's the issue here? I'm using RegexKitLite, which uses the ICU regex syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `negative lookbehind` is positioned incorrectly. Lookbehind's do not modify the input position, your `negative lookbehind` should come after your `\d{1,4}` expression:

```
(?i)\\d{1,4}(?<!v|vol|vol\\.|v\\.)(?![\\(]{0}.*\\))
```

Alternatively, just use a `negative lookahead` to accomplish the same purpose:

```
(?i)(?!v|vol|vol\\.|v\\.)\\d{1,4}(?![\\(]{0}.*\\))
```

Comment: I’ve noticed that a variable-width look-behind in the Java `Pattern` class can severely impact performance.  I haven’t used the ICU libraries though, just drooled over them, so I don’t know whether it’s still true there.

Comment: Quite right on the lookbehind issue - I misread the docs. However, it still fails to pick up numbers that aren't inside parentheses. Is my not-inside-parentheses logic flawed? Example: @"String of letters 703 (1234) (more words a  number 2 here) (more letters)"

Answer (score 1):

Finally ended up with this regex:

`(?i)\\d{1,4}(?<!v|vol|vol\\.|v\\.)(?![^\\(]*\\))`

The negative look-behind needed to change. Passes all my tests. Thanks to Alex for identifying the positioning of my NLB being wrong.