# Cocoa error 2048 when using NSRegularExpression in Cocoa

Tags: ios, regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I'm building a regular expression for use in a parser in an iOS app. Here's my code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex =
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=#EXT[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+)[^#][^\r\n]+"
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
                                            error:&regexError
 ];
if (regexError) {
    NSLog(@"regexError: %@", regexError);
    return nil;
}
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633416/regex-match-line-if-previous-line-satisfies-a-criteria#comment30894792_20633416).

This gives out this error:

`regexError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0x8e86670 {NSInvalidValue=(?<=#EXT[^`

Cocoa error 2048 is an `NSFormattingErrorMinimum` [according to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)... But there's literally no further explanation.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you trying to match a new line/line feed character? you've inserted a literal new line character into your regex... you need to instead insert the code for a newline. Try escaping as `\\n` etc.

**edit:**

You have to escape *all* special strings. For example you want your regex string to contain `\`+`r`, not a linefeed character. So you need to use `\\r` instead of `\r`.

i.e.

```
"(?<=#EXT[^\\r\\n]*[\\r\\n]+)[^#][^\\r\\n]+"
```

**edit 2:**

You cannot have unlimited length strings in your look-behind. So, no `*` and no `+` allowed. This is per the [ICU regex reference](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). (`NSRegularExpression` uses ICU regex syntax.)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to match a new line character. I tried this: `@"(?<=#EXT[^\r\\n]*[\r\\n]+)[^#][^\r\\n]+"` but I got the same error.

Comment: You have to escape all the special characters, now just `\n`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Turns out your look-behind is invalid. Do it without look-behind.

Comment: I tried this: `#EXT[^\\r\\n]*[\\r\\n]+[^#][^\\r\\n]+`. The error went away, but now it doesn't match my strings..

Comment: Well I answered the error question :) now you need to debug your regex. I use Reggy : https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24078/reggy