# NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern is not working in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, ios8, ios8.1

I am using following Regex:

```
NSString *pattern = @"KEYIDSTREQ(?<SpeakerID>.*?)#MEMNAMESTREQ(?<SpeakerName>.*?)#MEMSPEAKNUMSTREQ(?<SpeakerNumberToSpeak>.*?)#MEMTRSTREQ(?<Time>.*?)#REQLED(ON|OF)#TALKLED(ON|OF)#SUMLED(ON|OF)#STOPLED(ON|OF)LT(?<HexNo>.*?)";

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

if(!error) {
    // My code...
}
```

It is working correctly with iOS 9.0+ but when I run this code with iOS 8.1+ then I am getting following error message:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain 
Code=2048 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" 
UserInfo=0x16e19c60 {NSInvalidValue=KEYIDSTREQ(?<SpeakerID>.*?)#MEMNAMESTREQ(?<SpeakerName>.*?)#MEMSPEAKNUMSTREQ(?<SpeakerNumberToSpeak>.*?)#MEMTRSTREQ(?<Time>.*?)#REQLED(ON|OF)#TALKLED(ON|OF)#SUMLED(ON|OF)#STOPLED(ON|OF)LT(?<HexNo>.*?)}
```

What I am missing in that ? Any clue ?

Comment: Are you sure it worked at all? The last `.*?` never matched anything. Also, instead of `(ON|OF)`, you'd better use a simpler `O[NF]`

Comment: Yes, It works well with iOS 9.0+. I have tested with all the version. Try with this string: 

>KEYIDSTR=001^MEMNAMESTR=Member 1^MEMSPEAKNUMSTR=---^MEMTRSTR=0:00^REQLEDOF^TALKLEDOF^SUMLEDOF^STOPLEDOF<66

Comment: Look, [there is no match](https://regex101.com/r/dY3vR9/1).

Comment: @wiktor, Please use this string:

KEYIDSTREQ001#MEMNAMESTREQMember 1#MEMSPEAKNUMSTREQ---#MEMTRSTREQ1:00#REQLEDOF#TALKLEDOF#SUMLEDOF#STOPLEDOFLT67

Although, my question is not for matching, it gives error for iOS 8.0+ but for iOS 9.0+ its working fine. What is wrong here ?

Comment: Ok, then the issue is not related to the regex pattern itself. https://ideone.com/Iqd3No shows "nothing bad".

Comment: [Cocoa error 2048 when using NSRegularExpression in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640375/cocoa-error-2048-when-using-nsregularexpression-in-cocoa)?